# UIGestureRecognizerを別クラスで実装したい

Tags: ios, objective-c

あるViewControllerにジェスチャーを実装したいのですが、

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(getSwipe:)];

gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

これらのメソッドをこのViewControllerが持つ自作のGestureManagerというクラスに持たせることは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

「やりかたによる」と答えるしかないように思えます。
ポイントは、このコードです。

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

`UIGestureRecognizer`（のサブクラス）は、`UIView`（のサブクラス）に`add`して、はじめて機能する。このことを忘れなければ、実装を失敗することはないでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

これではダメですか？

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:yourManager action:@selector(getSwipe:)];

gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```